# When deadlocks occur in modern operating systems?

Tags: operating-system, deadlock

I know deadlocks was a hot research topic in past. But, even though I studied lots of modern operating systems, I cannot see any major problem about deadlocks now. I know some (most) resources which deadlocks can occur strictly managed by operating system itself and seems it prevent deadlocks someway, I really didn't see any case related to a deadlock. I know lots of features about resources handled different than others in popular systems with different design principles but, they can all maintain system deadlock-free.

Comment: It's not difficult to deadlock a couple threads in Linux/Windows.  Next time you write a Windows GUI app, create a thread in an event-handler and then immediately join it.  In the thread, make a SendMessage() call to the GUI thread before exiting.   The GUI thread will not handle any more messages until the thread exits.  The thread will not exit until the SendMessage()  call returns. Deadlock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use two mutexes in your program and in first thread close in sequence: mutex1, sleep(500ms), mutex2, in second thread: mutex2, sleep(1000ms), mutex1.

In systems. In windows (including 8.1) if your application uses `SendMessage` and broadcast `HWND_BROADCAST` - if one application is hung, your application also will be in hung state. Also in part cases of DDE communication (including `ShellExecute` for part of programs), if one application is not responsive, your application can be in hung state.

But you can use SendMessageTimeout...

The deadlock will always be possible if processes or threads will be synchronized. Synchronization of processes and threads is a "must-have" element of applications.

AND... SYSTEM-WIDE deadlock (Windows):
Save all your documents before this action.

```
Create HWND h1 with parent=0 or parent=GetDesktopWindow and styles 0x96cf0000
Create HWND h2 with parent=h1 and styles 0x96cf0000
Create HWND h3 with parent=h2 and styles 0x56cf0000 (here must be a child window).
Use ::SetParent(h1, h3);
```

Then click any of these windows.

The system will in cyclic (triangle) order try to reorder windows. The application is hung but if any other application will try to use SetWindowPos, the application will newer return from this function. The Task Manager won't help, the Alt+Ctrl+Del also stops to work. 100% of usage of CPU... Only hard reset will help you.

There is possibility to prevent it but this situation must be detected ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Operating system deadlocks still happen.  When a system has limited contended resources that it can't reclaim a deadlock is still possible.

In linux, look at kernel stalls, these happen when I/O doesn't release in a timely manner.  Kernel stalls are particularly interesting between vmware and guest operating systems.

For external instigators, deadlocks happen when san systems and networks have issues.

New release deadlocks happen fairly often while maturing a kernel, not per user, but as a whole from the community.

Ever get a blue screen or instant reboot?  Some of those are caused by lost resources.

Kernels are fairly mature, and have gotten good at reclaiming resources, but aren't perfect.

Most modern resource handlers tend to present as services now instead of being lockable objects.  Most resource sharing within the operating system relies on separate channels, alleviating much of the overlap.  There's a higher reliance on queues and toggles instead of direct locking contention on shared buffers.  These are generalities of trends in OS parts and pieces that contribute to less opportunity for deadlocks, but there's not a way to guarantee a deadlock less system.